# Internal DNS-server to override certain lookups

Tags: dns, routing

I have a few different servers at home. Some are exposed to the outside, and I have setup a domain for my home stuff. Let's say this is `myhome.mydomain.com`. I have also setup a wildcard DNS `*.myhome.mydomain.com` which points to the same server (both are CNAME records to my routers built in DDNS function).

This works perfectly from the outside. But from the inside something goes haywire. I guess it has something to do with routing from the inside to the outside to the inside... So as I see it my options are to either figure out why the routing is broken, or setup an internal DNS-server to point `myhome.mydomain.com` to my internal IP for this server, and forward the rest to my ISP's DNS or Googles or OpenDNS or something.

How do I setup this internal DNS server? I also want it to respond to the wildcard because my plan is to have an nginx proxy in front of all the services I wish to expose to the outside eventually.

Comment: On which os do you want to setup the DNS server?

Comment: Are you referring to resolving internal names (*i.e.*, into private, LAN addresses) or public names corresponding to routable IP addresses? Normally, from inside the LAN, it is best to use private addresses (and private names) so as to avoid **hairpinning**).

Comment: I have a linux box I want to run the dns-server on. I want to resolve ``myhome.domain.com`` to a LAN addres (``192.168.1.5``) when on the inside, but to my home public ip (``80.2.3.4``) when on the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outside part is already ok. The following steps are to enable the internal DNS server.

Set up dnsmasq on a local linux box.

Set it to listen on the interface connected to your LAN.

Set some external DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf` (or configure a custom resolv-file and add the DNS servers there). These DNS servers will be used to resolve anything that dnsmasq cannot resolve using its config file or the /etc/hosts contents.

Then:

- if you want *.myhome.mydomain.com resolved to a single internal ip add:

  ```
  address=/.myhome.mydomain.com/YOUR.IP.ADD.RESS
  ```

  in dnsmasq's config file (usually `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`)
- add other hosts that you want resolved by dnsmasq to `/etc/hosts` with the format:

  ```
  192.168.1.x name1.myhome.mydomain.com
  192.168.1.y name2.myhome.mydomain.com
  192.168.1.z name3.otherdomain.com
  ```

Set your box IP address as the DNS for your local network.

Comment: So if I want *.myhome.mydomain.com to go to 192.168.1.5, but otherserver.myhome.mydomain.com to go to 192.168.1.6, will it read the hosts-file first, and then the dnsmasq?

Comment: it's dnsmasq that when answering your requests will look at the /etc/hosts contents (on the machine it's running on)

Comment: Yes.. But which takes precedence when the "address" line is present with a wildcard in the dnsmasq.conf file?

Comment: According to dnsmasq man page for the option address: "Note that /etc/hosts and DHCP leases override this for individual names"

Comment: Notice that while internally you'll be able to resolve the different names to the different internal IPs, from outside you can count only on the wildcard resolving to the single public ip.

Comment: Thank you :) Like I said... I'll probably have an nginx proxy for everything I need to be available from the outside.